# How do I call a script with a wildcard pattern and two more arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, arguments, variable-substitution

I have this code to rename a bunch of files:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1
    do
        mv -i "${file}" "${file/pattern/replacement}"
    done
```

How do I replace "pattern" and "replacement" with $2 and $3?

This code does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1
    do
        mv -i "${file}" "${file/$2/$3}"
    done
```

I'm trying to rename using the following 3 arguments: `file_*.jpg jpg bak` (the result should be renaming all `*.jpg` files to `*.bak` files). But all it does is: `mv -i file_01.jpg file_01.jpg` (thus not renaming anything, since both mv arguments are identical, plus it stops at the first file, even when there are more `*.jpg` files). If I manually type `jpg` and `bak` into the bash script instead of `$2` and `$3` then it DOES work.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: How do you invoke that script?

Comment: Maybe add `#!/usr/bin/env bash` on top of the script, to make sure bash is invoked.

Comment: It looks like you are rewriting rename command ...

Comment: @Archemar: What rename command? Excuse my ignorance, but I don't know any rename command other than "mv"

Comment: see `man rename`

Comment: That command is not available for me. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call your script with

```
./script file_*.jpg jpg bak
```

But `*` gets expanded before it is passed to the script. Assuming you have the files `file_1.jpg`, `file_2.jpg` and `file_3.jpg` in your folder, this is what is invoked:

```
./script file_1.jpg file_2.jpg file_3.jpg jpg bak
```

which means that `${1} = file_1.jpg`, `${2} = file_2.jpg` and `${3} = file_3.jpg`.

It might be better if you write your script such, that (in your example): `${1} = jpg` and `${2} = bak`. Then you can store those variables in your script, invoke `shift 2` to get rid of them, and loop over all positional arguments simply by using

```
for file; do
    # do something
done
```

Comment: As written, the script would work if called as `./script 'file_*.jpg' jpg bak` as `$1` is unquoted, so subject to split+glob, so that `file_*.jpg` would be expanded at that point. Your advice of having $1=pat, $2=ret and the rest the list of files is certainly best though (1- to avoid having to quote the pattern, 2- to avoid confusing users of other shells with different globs than bash, 3- to allow patterns like `my file*`...)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My question shows that I'm still a newbie to Bash and basic Linux behaviour (such as how arguments are expanded). I've posted my own resulting code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I've come up with based on tips from @pfnuesel and @Stéphane Chazelas:

```
#!/bin/bash

preview="false"
found="false"

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Syntax: ren [-p] expression replacement files..."
else
    if [ "$1" == "-p" ] || [ "$1" == "-P" ]; then
        preview="true"
        shift
    fi

    expression=$1
    replacement=$2
    shift 2

    for file; do
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
            found="true"
            if [ "$preview" == "true" ]; then
                echo mv -i -- "${file}" "${file/$expression/$replacement}"
            else
                mv -i -- "${file}" "${file/$expression/$replacement}"
            fi
        fi
    done

    if [ "$found" != "true" ]; then
        echo >&2 "Couldn't find files with the specified wildcard"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: consider using `getopts` to process your options. For instance, had you used `getopts`, you would have been able to do `myscript -- -p -q files` to replace `-p` with `-q`, and `-ppp` would have meant the same as `-p`.

Comment: Your use of _needle_, _haystack_ and _wildcard_ words is confusing here.

Comment: Note that if your boolean variables are made to contain only `true` or `false`, you can just do `if "$found"` instead of `if [ "$found" = true ]`.

Comment: Note that `[ -f "$file" ]` is not for _file existence_, but that the file exists **and is a regular file** (or symlink to regular file). That would exclude all other types of file like fifo, device, directory...

Comment: Thanks a lot for reviewing my code and for all your comments, Stéphane! You're really helpful! I've implemented most of your suggestions, except getopts (I have to learn more about it) and `if [ "$found" ]`, because that results in true when $found contains "false" (it's a string after all; I used strings since booleans don't exist in Bash). Also I don't mind the `if [ -f "$file" ]` checking only for regular files. It's all I need for now.

Comment: BTW, it seems I'm reinventing the wheel here since there is an actual "rename" command I didn't know about the existence of, but it's not available on my machine, so my script will do. Plus, it's a nice exercise in Bash scripting :)

Comment: yes, rename (both util-linux, perl's and now separate perl script with more extensions) and also `mmv` and zsh's `zmv`...

Comment: Note that I said `if "$found"`, not `if [ "$found" ]`, as in run the command stored in `$found` (`false` and `true` being builtin bash commands), not the `[` command with the content of `$found` as argument.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's another intricacy I didn't know about :). About "mmv" and "zmv", those aren't available here, either

Comment: `zmv` is a function shipped with `zsh`, so you can use all the expansion operators and glob operators of `zsh` (use `autoload zmv` from within `zsh` to enable it). You can [search this site for `zmv`](/search?q=zmv) to see hundreds of examples.